# Export Users From Live Site to Import onto staging

Tags: import, export

I have a staging site copied from my live site that I'm working on adding some functionality. The problem is that new users are signing up on my live site. Once I'm done fixing the problems on my staging site I will want to make that my live site but want the users list to be up to date.

My question is if I use the export tool and export the users and import that file onto the staging site - will it duplicate already existing users or override everything? Ideally I want it to just override everything in order to have the most up to date list of users.

Answer (score 1):

You can try my favourite import/export plugin WP All Import and WP All Export http://www.wpallimport.com / http://www.wpallimport.com/export/

Or User Meta Pro http://user-meta.com/documentation/export-import/

You can use WP-CLI for an import too...

```
wp user import-csv /path/to/users.csv
```

http://wp-cli.org/commands/user/import-csv/